# null / false boolean value - Which uses more bytes in a Mysql database

Tags: mysql, boolean, storage

I have an innodb table which will store a large amount of records > 40 million plus, and some fields are booleans where null or false could suffice as a value. With this many records I'm concerned about space, so which would use more storage space: a value of null, or a value of false? I'm assuming null is not actually a value that's stored in the table whilst false is a real value.

Comment: Question depens on  the used storage engine

Comment: Added 'innodb' to the question, thanks